# How do I migrate existing Wordpress/WooCommerce users to LDAP?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ldap

I have a Wordpress/WooCommerce installation using Wordpress itself for authentication. I want to switch to LDAP-based authentication (e.g. OpenLDAP). How can I migrate existing users with minimal intervention on their part?

Ideally they would simply continue using their pre-existing credentials for Wordpress and for any other resources using the same LDAP database.

In addition, new users created via WooCommerce purchases should be created as LDAP users.

(Existing plugins like [Simple LDAP Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-ldap-login/) seem to handle creating Wordpress users for pre-existing LDAP credentials just fine. I'm looking for support in the other direction.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Esteban's advice I developed a solution as follows:

**Wordpress interface**

- Install Simple LDAP Login
- Install [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)
- Users authenticate against LDAP, fall back on Wordpress
- "Change password" sends them to new interface

**New interface**

- User logs in via new interface
- Users authenticate against LDAP, fall back on:

  - Authenticate against Wordpress via JWT. On success:
  - Create LDAP user (we have the password)
  - Delete Wordpress password hash (no longer needed, forces LDAP-based authentication in future)

**Workflow**

- Existing users can sign in via Wordpress or the new interface. Once they use the new interface (to sign in or change their password), they are migrated to LDAP-based authentication.
- New users are registered in LDAP. They can sign in via Wordpress or the new interface, both backed by LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to develop this task yourself. You could check tools like : https://lsc-project.org/start which will allow you to configure mapping and synchronising SQL database to LDAP directory and schedule the task regularly (or trigger it on new row in the DB)

Only point where you could have some problem would be the "keep their credentials". I don't know wordpress, but if the hashing and/or crypting mechanism of the passwords are not natively supported by OpenLDAP, you will have to hash the clear password of the user to store it with a mechanism compatible.

- One way would be to tell every user that the password will be reset and that they will have to retype it (some custom landing page where you authenticate the user with his credentials on the wordpress DB and if successful write the password on the LDAP)
- Another way would be to deploy some self service password with all account reset and a need to re-set them with a link send to their email (from the LDAP). There are tools like that, for example : https://ltb-project.org/documentation/self-service-password